# Styling -webkit-scrollbar to be shorter than the height of the container?

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar, margin

[image: See image for example]

I'm trying to style up the scrollbar so that it's positioned inside the scrollable area (container with scrollbar), effectively with margin just on the top & bottom of the bar itself.

In the example image, notice how the text flows past the bar, and how the image is positioned above it. Is this achievable?

Note: I'm aware the browser support for these things isn't the greatest, most likely will just have to use a polyfill for a bit.

Edit to clarify one thing: If the user were to scroll down on the example, the text should be visible up to the top edge of the image, if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who needs this answer:

```
main::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start,
main::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end {
    height: 6vh;
}
```